# Name of this crimp connector?

Tags: connector, identification, crimp, thermal-cutoff

What is the name of this crimp connector? It looks like a spade connector (female) with a missing tail. In the picture, it used to attach a thermal fuse. Does it require a special tool to install? Can you make your own by repurposing a spade connector...

[image: front]
[image: back]

Comment: I almost think that *is* a faston connector with its tail cut off. That's *weird*.

Comment: I'd be tempted to replace this with a butt splice, nickel if you need high temp.  Do you know what material the solid wire is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This kind of **crimp splice** connection is popular in appliances, as it requires no soldering and can be  used at relatively high temperatures. It comes off a roll of such connectors or a roll of strip brass, in which case it can be called a **band splice**.

I have emulated this with ferrules and a collet hand crimping tool in order to fix our prized sandwich maker by replacing the internal thermal fuse. They called it too close on the temperature rating and it was already the highest temperature easily available (240°C) so I moved it a bit to make it run slightly cooler.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have seen something like that before. The one that I examined seemed to have been spot welded. I believe that I may have either cut the spade of a spade connector or pried the original apart and reused it. I believe I crimped it and then soldered it.